# TeX4HT - How to add extra tag on theorem-like environments

Tags: tex4ht, html, make4ht, tex4ebook

I am using TeX4HT to convert LaTeX into HTML. I need the HTML structure of theorem-like environment to be like below:

1. The `<div>` class attribute value should be the name of the type, such as theorem, lemma, or remark, based on the type of the environment. For instance, these tags could look like `<div class="theorem">` or `<div class="lemma">`.
2. Theorem label and head should be like below with the different class attribute value

   `<span class='thmlbl'><a id='x1-1002r1'></a>Theorem 1.1<span>`

   `<span class="thmhead">(CG as a special case of GUG).</span>`

I tried `\Configure{newtheorem}`, but I don't know how to update the expected result.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}[CG as a special case of GUG]\label{th(0)} 
Let $D'=\{(0,0)^t,(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)^t, (\beta_1,\beta_2)^t, (-\alpha_1-\beta_1,-\alpha_2-\beta_2)^t\}$ be an integer digit set and $M\in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ be an expanding matrix. If $\alpha_1\beta_2-\alpha_2\beta_1\notin 2\mathbb{Z}$, then $\mu_{M,D'}$ is a spectral measure if and only if $M\in M_2(2\mathbb{Z})$.
\end{theorem}




\begin{theorem}\label{th1} 
Let $D'=\{(0,0)^t,(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)^t, (\beta_1,\beta_2)^t, (-\alpha_1-\beta_1,-\alpha_2-\beta_2)^t\}$ be an integer digit set and $M\in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ be an expanding matrix. If $\alpha_1\beta_2-\alpha_2\beta_1\notin 2\mathbb{Z}$, then $\mu_{M,D'}$ is a spectral measure if and only if $M\in M_2(2\mathbb{Z})$.
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Can you confirm that what command you are using for `TeX4ht` conversion?

Comment: @MadyYuvi, I am using Make4ht.exe

Comment: Is this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369043/how-to-configure-the-customized-theorem-environment-in-tex4ht helpful for you?

Comment: @MadyYuvi, thanks for your suggestion, I already looked that solution in that solution also label and titles in same <label> tag but i need different tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\Configure{newtheorem}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP
     \HCode{<div class="\@currenvir">}\par\noindent\HCode{<span
           class="thmlbl">}\NoFonts}
   {\EndNoFonts\HCode{</span>}}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\par\indent\ShowPar}

\def\@beforethmname#1{\HCode{</span><span class="thmhead">}#1}
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \deferred@thm@head{\the\thm@headfont \thm@indent
    \@ifempty{#1}{\let\thmname\@gobble}{\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}{\let\thmnumber\@gobble}{\let\thmnumber\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#3}{\let\thmnote\@gobble}{\let\thmnote\@beforethmname}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \the\thm@headpunct
    \thmheadnl % possibly a newline.
    \hskip\thm@headsep
  }%
  \ignorespaces}

\Css{.thmlbl{font-weight: bold;}}
\makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

It is a copy of the default TeX4ht configuration for theorems with two changes. It inserts the current theorem environment name as a class, thanks to the `\@currenvir` command, and I also changed the class to the name you wanted.

Unfortunately, it is not easy to insert tags between the theorem number and label, so we had to copy definition of `\@begintheorem` from `amsmath.sty` and here we can insert a modified version of `\thmnote`, named `\beforethmname`, which prints the label. Here we can close the `thmlbl` span element and open the `thmhead`.

This is the result:

[image]

```html
 <div class='theorem'>
<!-- l. 11 --><p class='noindent'><span class='thmlbl'>
<a id='x1-2r1'></a>
Theorem 1</span><span class='thmhead'> (CG as a special case of GUG).   </span><span class='cmti-10'>Let</span> \(D'=\{(0,0)^t,(\alpha _1,\alpha _2)^t, (\beta _1,\beta _2)^t, (-\alpha _1-\beta _1,-\alpha _2-\beta _2)^t\}\) <span class='cmti-10'>be an integer digit set and</span> \(M\in M_2(\mathbb {Z})\)
<span class='cmti-10'>be an expanding matrix. If</span> \(\alpha _1\beta _2-\alpha _2\beta _1\notin 2\mathbb {Z}\)<span class='cmti-10'>, then</span> \(\mu _{M,D'}\) <span class='cmti-10'>is a spectral measure if and only if</span> \(M\in M_2(2\mathbb {Z})\)<span class='cmti-10'>.</span>
</p>
   </div>
<!-- l. 13 --><p class='indent'>
</p>
   <div class='theorem'>
<!-- l. 18 --><p class='noindent'><span class='thmlbl'>
<a id='x1-3r2'></a>
Theorem 2.  </span> <span class='cmti-10'>Let</span> \(D'=\{(0,0)^t,(\alpha _1,\alpha _2)^t, (\beta _1,\beta _2)^t, (-\alpha _1-\beta _1,-\alpha _2-\beta _2)^t\}\) <span class='cmti-10'>be an integer digit set and</span> \(M\in M_2(\mathbb {Z})\) <span class='cmti-10'>be an expanding matrix. If</span> \(\alpha _1\beta _2-\alpha _2\beta _1\notin 2\mathbb {Z}\)<span class='cmti-10'>, then</span>
\(\mu _{M,D'}\) <span class='cmti-10'>is a spectral measure if and only if</span> \(M\in M_2(2\mathbb {Z})\)<span class='cmti-10'>.</span>
</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful advice; everything is operating as intended.

Comment: i have an another doubt is possible to get the font style formatting like <italic> <bold> tag for the theorem label and head as in the dvi output i am using `NoFonts` option for genereating html file

Comment: @sizr Sure, you can change `<span>` elements to `<it>` or `<b>`.

Comment: thanks for the suggesting, sometime theorem head in bold, and remark head in italic in this case, both head style are same formatting in the HTML file, but should be in different formatting as in DVI

Comment: @sizr I was wrong, the correct tag for italics is `<i>`, not `<it>`. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: No, Michal, I just need the Head styles as like in the DVI/PDF output; for example if the Theorem head is in Bold,  then  it should be in the <b> bold tag; if the head in Italic, then it should be in <i> tag, as per your suggestion all the heads will be in the same format in HTML

Comment: Ah, in this case you can remove the `\Css`, `\NoFonts` and `\EndNoFonts` commands. You won't get `<i>` or `<b>` tags, but `<span>`, but it will be styled using CSS to use the same font style as the original.